# how to keep GameObjects when changing the scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to use `DontDestroyOnLoad` method to keep the prefabs I instantiate(thumb_1 and thumb_2) in "TimeBarContent" 
TimeBar is a scrollview and TimeBarContent is the content objec comes with scrollview under viewport
I instantiate prefabs to scrollview and I want to keep them when I comeback to MainScene again
I have some other scenes which are gonna open do some stuff and when done it will comeback to MainScene

I am loading the scenes with `LoadSceneMode.Single` because I think this will keep a better performance

I tried somethings and dont know if I am on the right way but with mistakes or completely wrong

1. I write `DontDestroyOnLoad(timebar)` at awake method in mainscene
2. I added a script to timebar

````
bool created = false;
private void Awake()
{
    if (!created)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        created = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

```
both of these attempts failed 
what I understand if I manage to put the timebar or timecontent in DontDestroyOnLoad under the hierarchy
at play the object will kept and when the mainscene is loading again because it is kept, instead of new one the kept one will be shown with the prefabs in it
how can I do that?
````

Comment: its not clear what you mean by both attempts failed.. or what is or is not happening that you expected. If you dont destroy it, it will remain

Comment: when I come baack to main scene the thumb_1 and 2 arent there

Comment: because the canvas goes.. it will take it with it.. you need to keep the whole hierarchy, why not put it in its own canvas then it will stay (as long as you protect that canvas)

Comment: I thought using multiple scenes instead of a 1 scene and a lot of canvas is better performance I am gonna run it in mobile thats why
so if canvas goes and takes everything with it whats the use of DontDestroyOnLoad

Comment: you can have multip[le canvases, in fact apparently its kinda good to do so. so try it

Comment: I know I can but having 1 scene and a lot of canvases is too much. 
instead of that I want to load scenes for canvases will reduce workload

Comment: then do that, this question becomes irrelevant

Comment: I am doin it but I from changing scenes my prefabs are destroyed I want o keep them

Comment: You cant keep sub parts of a heirachy. You have to keep that whole element, OR remake it.. if you load an additive scene you then have multiple scenes, but you cant always have your cake and eat it - and multiple scenes is usually way more complex than a couple of canvases would be

Answer (score 0):

Attach this script to any GameObject you want keep between scenes. Remember that [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) it's called once during the whole lifetime of a GameObject.

```
public class DontDestroyOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
   void Awake()
   {
      DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
   }
}
```

Comment: I added to my script for prefab since I want to keep them but they werent there

Comment: Remember that DontDestroyOnLoad works only on root elements of the hierarchy, it can't be applied to a single child.

Comment: dont know that
so in the picture of my hierarchy what can I use timebar or canvas?

Comment: In your case, Canvas is the root element of the hierarchy.

Comment: so is it wise to keep canvas in DontDestroyOnLoad for performance.
I can reput my prefabs I keep the data in a static class